# i have noodjs npm install problem core-js@3.15.2 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`

Tags: npm-install

im noob programer

i wanna tensorflow experience

but cant intall npm at noodjs

because this npm install error

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! core-js@3.15.2 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@3.15.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

plz help me

how can fix this error ..... :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case this had to due with being unable to use bash due to missing subversion of linux.

check if you can run bash in command prompt.